# HIbernate Free Query

Tags: hibernate, orm

I would like to query using hibernate given a particulay query string
I did it like this:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
List<String> result = session.createQuery("Select item_value from cb_items").list();  
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.clear();  
return result;
```

Is this right? or do i have to substitute the column name with the fields in my pojo/bean and the table name with my pojo/bean name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to substitute the column name with the field name, and the table name with the Entity's class name, and follow a little [different sytax](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/queryhql.html).

Answer (score 0):

I missed the mapping in my hibernate.cfg.xml